# How to update Customer Information messages in Drupal :: Ubercart

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

i recently installed Ubercart module and manged to configure most of the shopping cart. One of the issues i am having is finding a place to update the Customer Information message

"**Enter a valid email address for this order or click here to login with an existing account and return to checkout.**"

to whatver i want. Could not figure out where i can find this piece of text so that i can update it. This message is appearing on `/cart/checkout` page:

```
http://<<site>>/cart/checkout
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oooold question, I know, but I did it with the following:

In a custom module, you can add it to `_form_alter`, i.e.

```
function mymodule_form_alter((&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
     $form['panes']['customer']['primary_email']['#description'] = 
          t('Your custom message goes here.');     
}
```